# Dilema con sistema muy particular. FAX

Tags: windows, fax

Tengo un dilema que no puedo resolver y agradeceria muchísimo a quien
pudiera darme una mano.

Estamos armando un sistema para un cliente, y resulta que es un sistema para un modelo de negocios muy particular. El hecho es que el cliente se maneja hace años con un sistema viejo que utiliza fax.

El tipo tiene clientes que le envian fax para mandarle datos. En el nuevo
sistema que le estamos haciendo se va a implementar todo online, pero igualmente esta persona quiere tener disponible el sistema de fax en caso de que se caiga la conexión a internet o haya algun problema con el servidor, el nececita tener una vía de comunicación inmediata y fiable con los clientes.

El problema esta en que quiere que el sistema que le estamos haciendo funcione con los fax de la misma manera que el sistema viejo que el tiene.

El sistema de el funciona de esta manera:

El llama a su cliente y le pide que le envíe la información por fax, el cliente sin colgar el teléfono toca cierta tecla en su sistema para enviar el fax (la línea esta conectada a una placa pci modem en la pc), la llamada que tienen en curso se interrumpe, pero sin ser cortada, y aparece una barra de progreso en la pc del cliente, la cual al llegar al 100% se transmite el fax, y la comunicación telefónica se retoma.

Mi problema es que no sé como hacer funcionar el fax de esta manera, estuve viendo con el asistende de windows y lo manda todo bien pero siempre y cuando del otro lado haya un fax en modo automático para recibir, pero el cliente no quiere este modo automático, quiere que siga funcionando de la misma manera.

Yo pensaba en buscar algun programa que maneje fax hecho en visual y hacer la llamada a ese programa al momento de mandar el fax pero no he encontrado mucho.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: He cambiado las etiquetas porque según veo esto no está asociado a Java. Por favor brinda más detalle sobre la tecnología que utilizas para implementar tu sistema. Aunque te recomendaría convivir con el sistema antiguo y ver una manera de integrar esta funcionalidad del antiguo con lo nuevo que están creando.

Comment: Te has planteado asterisk?

Comment: @Spidvmp es una muy buena recomendación y, quizás deberías publicarlo con un poco más de detalle como respuesta.